# Get all permutations that pad a list with zeroes

Tags: python, permutation

I have a list `ls` of length `n` and want to get all lists of length `m` (where m > n) that contain `ls` in the same order, plus (m - n) zeroes, inserted at each possible combination of positions.

For example: `ls = [1, 2, 3]` and `m = 4` should return

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

and `ls = [1, 2, 3]` and `m = 5` should return

```
[[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 0],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 3],
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 3],
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

The solution should be fast and memory efficient - in particular, it should avoid generating duplicate solutions. Any help is appreciated!

A working (but inefficient) attempt:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3]
m = 4

from itertools import permutations

n = len(ls)
results = []
for t in set(permutations('1' * n + '0' * (m - n))):
    idxs = [i for i, j in enumerate(t) if j == '1']
    result = [0] * m
    for idx, value in zip(idxs, ls):
        result[idx] = value
    results.append(result)
```

Comment: Where is your current attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` to generate every combination of places to insert zeroes.  Then use a list comprehension to select 0 or the next original element to build the new list.

```
# Pad list orig with zeroes, out to "m" total elements.
from itertools import combinations

orig = [1, 2, 3]
m = 5
n = len(orig)

padded = []

for pad_idx in combinations(range(m), m-n):
    t = orig[:]
    padded.append( [0 if i in pad_idx else t.pop(0)
                    for i in range(m)] )

print(padded)
```

Output (formatted for readability):

```
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 0, 2, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 0, 3], 
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 0], 
 [1, 0, 0, 2, 3], 
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 3], 
 [1, 0, 2, 3, 0], 
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 3], 
 [1, 2, 0, 3, 0], 
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use a list comprehension? `[0 if i in pad_idx else orig[:].pop() for i in range(m)]` does not work.

Comment: Ah, got it: Define the inner list comprehension as a function and use that function (with `orig[:]` as input argument) in the outer list comprehension.

Comment: Nice insight; yes, that will do it.